# Issue using Mercure Hub

Tags: php, symfony, mercure

I am having some issues with my NotificationService on my UAT environment, but, oddly, this is working fine on my local server.

> $ php7 bin/console cache:clear
>
> In DefinitionErrorExceptionPass.php line 54:
>
> Cannot autowire service "App\Service\NotificationService": argument
> "$hub" of method "__construct()" references   interface
> "Symfony\Component\Mercure\HubInterface" but no such service exists.
> Did you create a class that implements this interface?

```
class NotificationService {
  public function __construct(..., HubInterface $hub, ...) {
```

The symfony/mercure package provided both HubInterface and Hub class implementing this interface.
I just resetted the project on UAT server and this error keeps throwing.
My Symfony project is up-to-date (v5.2.11) and so mercure & mercure bundle.

Have you an idea about what is missing ?

Comment: And you have cleared cache, cleared Redis or Memcached if used etc? Maybe run php composer.phar install again to clear autoload? or php composer.phar dump-autoload.

Comment: Do you have declaring your service in services.yaml ? For me i had to do it (symfony 5.4)